# How to handle the output of this subprocess?

Tags: python

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kali/Desktop/file.py", line 12, in 
if "not extract" not in subprocess_return:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

b'' <--- The output from "print(subprocess_return)"

I am a python beginner and it is the first time I using subprocess and I am heavily confused by the the suggestions I found on the internet. Maybe someone could explain how to avoid this error and get the output of this command as a string, which I can use in the process. I tried to write this script for a CTF on THM, so don´t worry, I am doing nothing illegal

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("/usr/share/wordlists")
with open("rockyou.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as file:
    array = file.readlines()

for string in array:
    subprocess = subprocess.Popen("steghide extract -sf /home/kali/Downloads/jose-fontano-pZld9PiPDno-unsplash.jpg -p " + string.rstrip("\n"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess_return = subprocess.stdout.readline()
    print(subprocess_return)        # I used this to check the output of "subprocess.stdout.readline()", which I wanted to be a string
    if "not extract" not in subprocess_return:
        print("----------- THIS IS IT: " + string.rstrip('\n'))
        break
```

Comment: ```subprocess.call()``` shows the output of commands as well

Answer (score 1):

First change the name of your variables because you will be overloading module names.

Then the message is quite explicit:
The type of the value returned by `stdout.readline` is a **byte**, yet when `if` you compare it with a **str**.
You can't compare things whose types are different (summarizing a lot)

So you have two possible solutions:

- Either `"not extract"` become a **byte** by adding a `b` before the first quotation mark (like this `b"not extract"`), but this is hard coded, it's not great, you can use the function `encode()` ([tuto](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-to-bytes/))
- Either you decode the output of `stdout.readline()` (by doing this `subprocess_return.decode()`) ([tuto](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm))